# @ symbol at the bottom when search using / in vi

Tags: unix, vi

I open a file in unix with vi, then do the search using /, it finds an occurrence but it also displays @ symbol at the bottom, when I try to scroll down, the @ symbol disappears.  I'm not sure if this @ symbol was something I entered accidentally when I was modifying the the file last time.

Comment: That means the last line on the screen does not show the complete line.

Comment: In other words: when the bottom line is too long too fit, it will be visually truncated until your cursor movements give more lines for displaying the complete line.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at : 
http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/vi.1.html

"Terminals with limited local intelligence
 might display lines on the screen marked with an @.  These indicate
 space on the screen not corresponding to lines in the file.  (These
 lines can be removed by entering a ^R, forcing the editor to retype
 the screen without these holes.)"